# Python - co-ownership in large database

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I have a large database (circa 9m records) in the form:

user id, product id, qty

I want to understand the frequency with which owners of one product, own every other product.

I've attempted to do this with list comprehension:

```py
for title in sampled_list:
    cross_owners[title]=dict()
    for title_2 in sampled_list:
        cross_owners[title_2] = dict()
        a = [x for x in owns_list if x[1] == title]
        b = [x for x in owns_list if x[1] == title_2]
        c = [x for x in a if x[0] in b[0]]
        if len(c) > 0:
            print(title)
            print(title_2)
            print(len(c))
            cross_owners[title][title_2] = len(c)
```

This works, but is slow and there's essentially 50k products so a lot of possible permutations.

I've a sense that I should be using pandas or something more sophisticated, but I'm struggling to see how I should implement that.

Comment: Use a GROUP BY with a SUM(qty) expression .You will get a great many result rows, so it will be convenient to start by requesting only those summary rows that show large quantities, with a WHERE or HAVING clause.

Comment: Stick with raw  SQL, at least initially. You do not yet know how many result rows you will have. Exploratory analysis in SQL will set you up to be better informed when you decide to use a list comprehension, pandas, or some other in-memory reporting technique.

Comment: @J_H regardless of the number of rows, I'll need to run the full analysis and in future repeat for other metrics than ownership (e.g. page views).  I've poked around in the data set and I know overlaps are to be pretty sparse, but that's the analysis I need to run.